# "Nightly" a good place for experimental features?

Tags: version-control, builds, release-management, build-system

In my day job I work on a tightly controlled project with features and overall scope ultimately decided on by committee.

Often the final features are the result of a single (or multiple) member's needs.
Thus every now and then an idea lands on my desk that can, technically speaking, be implemented but may not actually make it into the final release.

I've only taken over the project recently and, as it stands, there are two main branches (both linked to an equally titled build pipeline). `Testing` and `Production`.

I plan on introducing a `Nightly` branch/build (where such experimental functionality would be backed up and built from a `Staging` branch or subtree, so it can be removed from the regular `Nightly` branch on the fly) pipeline fairly soon and am wondering: Is `Nightly` the right place for such experimental functionality?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the length and complexity of the build process, and how many of these "experimental" features actually exist at one time, I would suggest to use feature branches for each of them, with the build system setup to build and test them independently. Then, if a feature build is successful, you can prepare a release candidate containing some number of features, and focus on integration testing between them. This will help ensure that the development and testing process for each is clear, and not muddled by what might be going on in a different experimental feature (one which may be breaking many things, let's say).

In general, this approach should be taken for all code, not sure features which are "experimental" in order to keep mainline branches clean, and potentially releasable at all times.

Also, "Nightly" isn't really a great name for a branch. It describes *when* something is intending to be run, not *what* it is, which is somewhat confusing. What if you wanted to test these things more often? Or in the morning?